# Regarding SafeArrayPutElement

Tags: c, unicode, atlcom

FYI I am begginer in COM\ATL and unicode

I am using `SafeArrayPutElement(safearray*,LONG,void*)` in my code and the problem is...

here, the function works fine when i give the third parameter as `L"ItWorks"`
i.e

```
SafeArrayPutElement(safearray*,LONG, L"ItWorks");
```

but if i use

```
wchar_t str;
str = 'a';
SafeArrayPutElement(safearray*,LONG,&str);
```

this function fails saying `E_OUTOFMEMORY`

here my need is, i have a string in `char*` variable, some how i need to use this as the THIRD parameter for the above function.
Can anyone please help me in this regard.

TIA

Naveen

Comment: Post real code, passing safearray* and LONG to the function can never compile.  Strings in a SAFEARRAY must be BSTR, not wchar_t.

Answer (score 2):

The only string type that is safe to use in COM in a `BSTR`, not a raw `wchar_t*`.  This is because a `BSTR` contains extra internal data that COM uses for marshalling purposes.  Use `SysAllocString()` or `SysAllocStringLen()` to allocate a new `BSTR` from a `wchar_t*`, and then use `SysFreeString()` to free it when you are finished using it, eg:

```
BSTR bstr = SysAllocString(L"ItWorks");
SafeArrayPutElement(..., bstr);
SysFreeString(bstr);
```

.

```
wchar_t str = L'a'; 
BSTR bstr = SysAllocStringLen(&str, 1);
SafeArrayPutElement(..., bstr);
SysFreeString(bstr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Here what is the alternate for 'L' in L'a', coz i already have a string in a varaiable so how to convert it

Comment: What kind of variable are you using? I showed you how to convert `wchar_t` and `wchar_t*`. Are you using something else?